# project always running with old code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I was trying to try out and create a .app file for my application and so I followed a [tutorial](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html). 
After doing this and running the app again on the simulator it always runs with the old code that I have. Why is this? I tried reverting everything back again, but it just won't.

I tried printing something when the app loads, but the app that runs didn't print anything
UPDATE:

I found a fix which is to revert back my bundle identifier to the old one. Why does this work? What if I want to create a binary again to be distributed in the app store, what should I do from this point?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have two apps with the same bundle identifier on the simulator, and Xcode starts the wrong one.

Try to delete everything from the simulator.
Open the `iOS Simulator` menu in the main menu and select `Reset Content and Settings...`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before and for some reason it just didn't update all the files in the bundle that it deployed to the device/simulator. Just delete the app from the device/simulator and redeploy. When it happened to me it didn't create a second app it just didn't completely update the bundle.